# Lines are not appeared in the graph

Tags: matlab, plot, graphics, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot the following function in MATLAB, but The lines are not shown up. Can anyone help me with it please.
Thank you.

```
x=1;
PiD=10;
PiC=20;
PiP=50;
Vhigh=4;
Vlow=0;
Vmax=5;
Vmin=-1;
A1=2;
A0=-4;
Dt=[(Vmax/A1)-(Vmax/A0)]+[((Vlow-Vmin)+(Vmax-Vhigh))/A1]+[((Vmax-Vhigh)+(Vlow-Vmin))/A0];
for i=-x:0.1:x
DPiI=PiD+[PiC*(Vhigh/A1)]+PiP*i+PiC*i;
PiE=DPiI/Dt;
end
plot (x,PiE)
```

Comment: Any errors? Or is it just giving you no errors with a blank graph? Also try `plot(i,PiE)` because `x` appears to only be a single value, unlike `i` which is an array.

Comment: No errors. It just returns a blank graph even with the I instead of x.

Comment: Okay wait. Sorry I told you the wrong thing. So what ends up happening is that once `PiE` runs through the `for` loop, its final value will be when `i=1` and thus setting `PiE` equaling to a single value. I understand what you're trying to do. It looks like you're trying to plot a function using a `for` loop. This isn't the proper way to approach this. You need to make `PiE` a function with respect to `x`.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do it or if you can do it for me as I am totally new to MATLAB

Comment: So you _are_ indeed plotting a line but the reason why you can't see anything is because `PiE` is equal to 28.2 for all `x` values.

Answer (score 1):

I made some additions to lhopital's answer and it seems to pass initial testing.

```
...
for i=-x:0.1:x
   DPiI=PiD+[PiC*(Vhigh/A1)]+PiP*i+PiC*i;
   PiE(j)=DPiI/Dt;
   i2(j) = i;
   j=j+1;
end
plot (i2,PiE,'bo-')
```

Comment: You should preallocate the arrays, and you don’t initialize `j`.

Comment: That really helped me. I really appreciate your effort. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
The PiE variable is a scalar. Try making it a vector as follows:
...
PiE = []
j = 1;
Dt=[(Vmax/A1)-(Vmax/A0)]+[((Vlow-Vmin)+(Vmax-Vhigh))/A1]+[((Vmax-Vhigh)+(Vlow- 
Vmin))/A0];
for i=-x:0.1:x
DPiI=PiD+[PiC*(Vhigh/A1)]+PiP*i+PiC*i;
PiE(j)=DPiI/Dt;
j=j+1;
end
plot (x,PiE)
```

Comment: That’s not valid MATLAB code, `j++` has no meaning.